# List Button Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom object called Fund Event with two fields called Grantee(lookup to Account) and Grantor(Master-Detail to Account).I have a list button on Fund Event with content source as visualforce page.And then added that list button to both the related lists Grantee and Grantor on Account pagelayout.I need to pre populate Grantee/Grantor field from where it was initiated (button).I am not able to find out from where it is clicked (which related list on Account) to prepopulate the Grantor or Grantee on the visualforce page.Is there a way to find out from where it was clicked from the url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use URL instead of having Visualforce page as **Content Source**.

`in URL: /apex/<VF pagename>?source =fromTestPage`

in the destination page you can identify the source using **source** parameter.